# Appcelerator Titanium - Using Model as dynamic theme

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Will this be a good idea:

I recently asked a question about themes (letting the user choose a theme and immediately applying it). To do this I had the thought of using Models and binding - which I used the opportunity to finally learn.
I got the desired result - creating a theme and applying it using a model with data binding, and in my test app I did the following:

app.tss
    "Label": {
        backgroundColor: "{theme.backgroundColor}"
    }

(of course in a real app there will be much more definitions and much more bindings.

Doing this requires that I include my Model in every page like this (index.xml):

```
<Alloy>
    <Model src="theme" />

    <Window class="container" layout="vertical">
        <View
            id="test"
            width="150"
            height="150"
            top="10">
        </View>

        <Label id="label" onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>
        <Label onClick="doClick" top="10">Hello, World</Label>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

(In my real app I'm using an implementation of cross-platform navigation control so I will just pass this model when I open the window in a single place)

Obviously doing this kind of thing will create many binding for pretty much each element on the page. I don't exactly know what is going on behind the scenes, but I'm guessing that it creates a listener for each such binded value - which results in many listeners, a lot of overhead and generates more code for the page.

Guessing I'm pretty much answering my own question - is this path recommended to continue investigating? How bad is this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using classes and re-applying them when it changes. You only have to monitor for an event at one place per controller

You can take a look at the example I wrote about dynamic styling based on orientation on [GitHub](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-orientation-styling)

You can do that like this:

```
".DynamicLabel[if=Alloy.Globals.isPortrait]": {}
```

You should be using Backbone events, like also specified in the repository I linked above.

Alloy.js:

```
Alloy.Globals.events = _.clone(Backbone.Events);
```

Controller.js:

```
Alloy.Globals.events.on('orientationchange', () => {
```

**But**: This is very complicated and introduces complexity you don't need. The events part I wouldn't recommend for a complicated application. But.. it is possible!

What I would recommend for a complex application, is use the `if` filters in the `tss` and just close and re-open the controllers you want to have re-styled.

Comment: What if one of the controllers I will need to close and reopen (and I'm guessing not just a Window `close()` and `open()`) is the main window? It will cause the entire app quit, won't it? What is the correct way to close and re-open a controller?

Comment: in case of Android when I have that functionality, I always use the `index` controller as the main one (just have nothing in it, but do open it). That way you can still close your "main" controller without the app exiting. In case of iOS, open a new window before closing the other one. That should work fine

Comment: But then in android when the user presses the back button on you "main" window (at least what is the main window in his mind) it will just show a blank page.

Comment: Make your own main window "exitOnClose: true" and when you want to close it to reopen don't forget to set it to `false` right before closing it ;)